# http request not working

Tags: xml, http, curl

I'm trying to retrieve `xml` data using the service from `apfy.me` like this

```
curl -H "x-apfy-authorization: [Your API key]" \http://apfy.me/www.blocket.se/burken/GetCategories
```

but that throws the following error:

> curl: (1) Protocol  http not supported or disabled in libcurl

when I try to run the command in terminal on my mac.

I have no experience in `curl`, I just want an ordinary url string to fetch the `xml` data. Is there a way to translate the curl command with header appended to a single url string?

Answer (score 0):

remove the `/`after the quote and before `http` . So try `curl -H "x-apfy-authorization: [Your API key]"  http://apfy.me/www.blocket.se/burken/GetCategories`. Once I removed the `/`, `curl` was successful in my environment and I wasn't getting the `curl: (1) Protocol  http not supported or disabled in libcurl` anymore.

Comment: Maybe that's it, but now I get the error <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><APFyError Code="110" LastFetchSuccess="" LastParseSuccess="" /> . According to the response code, 110 = API Key malformed. Maybe there is a special way to type the key??

Comment: OK, I created a new API key and then it worked, thanks